# why map method won't return array items inside my span? -REACT

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

lets say we have array of object like this

```
dynamicField : [
{a: ['One','Two'], b: '1'},
{a: ['One'], b: '1'},
{a: ['One','Two','Three'], b: '1'}
]
```

i want to show all strings inside `property a` in a span

my code

```js
 {dynamicField.length > 0 &&
        dynamicField.forEach((item) =>
          item[a].map((arrayItem,index) => <span key={index}>{arrayItem}</span>)
        )}
```

before writing `<span>{arrayItem}</span>`
i did a  `console.log(arrayItem)` and map method returned every item in array but it won't show it in span. what is wrong with this code?

Comment: You are missing closing ' tag, after Three in the third row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`forEach` callback doesn't return the results, you need to use two maps:

```js
 let data = [
    {a: ['One','Two'], b: '1'},
    {a: ['One'], b: '1'},
    {a: ['One','Two','Three'], b: '1'}
    ]
    
let result = data.map(x=>x.a.map(y=>y)) // use spans in last map

console.log(result)
```